# Modifying all subviews except for one

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, ios10

I have many subview elements under a single view which contain buttons, labels, ...etc. Please take a quick look at the below screenshot.

When I click a button I want all subviews disappear/hide except for the first subview which is UIImageView containning the background image.

How can I achieve that?

[image: none]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a parent view

```
let viewContainer : UIView = ...
```

you can hide all the children views but the ones of type `UIImageView`

```
viewContainer.subviews.forEach {
    if $0 is UIImageView == false { $0.isHidden = true }
}
```

Comment: I have something in my app that does this a bit more generically (that's not a good thing). Awesome answer!

Comment: I tried to do this but i got an error "Expression resolves to an unused I-value"

Comment: I got it fixed. I think in swift 3 you need to add $0.isHidden = true